# using the node editor with multiple entry points

Tags: blend4web

I'm using blend4web and have some different 'switch select' behaviours set up, one moves an object up on click and down on second click.

The other changes the colour of an object based on click of another object.

Both behaviours work independently of each other but not together, it seems that I cant switch between entry points?

Also clicking any other object in the scene (no behaviour defined on the object) stops either entry point working / behaviour being carried out.

can someone point me in the right direction I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You probably better ask that over at the [Blend4Web Forum](https://www.blend4web.com)

Answer (score 1):

> Both behaviours work independently of each other but not together, it seems that I cant switch between entry points?

Indeed, the current setup depicted on the screenshot suggest independent behavior.

> Also clicking any other object in the scene (no behaviour defined on the object) stops either entry point working / behaviour being carried out.

You need to connect the miss socket with some socket before the switch select node.